# Entity object as HQL parameter

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, parameters, hql

I have the following question, which is not covered in [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html_single/#querycriteria-param). Or I just couldn't find the answer there. Googling doesn't give me details also.

If we use an Entity object as a parameter and bind it to an HQL using Query.setParameter, what happens next?

- Does hibernate uses only an entity ID of a mapped parameter object to build the SQL 'where' query?
- Or Hibernate uses some extra logic (maybe in some cases) which is not limited to ID only? For example, hibernate add additional fields in SQL which are not primary keys.
- Is it dangerous to use detached Entity object as a parameter?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think hibernate uses id of related object , but it can be aplaid only for object wich has named property id and it will crate join in the sql. When you reference entity by its id object.id hibernate wil not have use join.  Also the object used as parametr have to be attached to session.

Comment: You think if an object is not attached to a session, an exception will be thrown? It looks like in our application no exception happens and the object is detached. I'm not sure if this is ok and I shouldn't attach the object saving DB traffic.

Comment: I am not sure about this but if its working you can use it. But I think is better to use directly object properties to set up parameters. object.anotherobject.id  = comparatorobject.id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the SQL it will simply compare using the ids.  The entity you bind does not have to be managed within that session as the comment on your question suggests.

Essentially what happens is that Hibernate will attempt to resolve the entity type of the entity instance it is given.  It will then use that type to bind the JDBC parameter value, which will write just the identifier.  So the assumption here is that the entity instance can resolved to its "entity type".  That is usually easy in most situations.  Where it gets difficult is in the case of Hibernate-specific "entity name" features.